# Proving columns of a commutative diagram of $R-$modules are exact

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology

[image]

Consider the attached commutative diagram of $R$-modules, where the central column is a complex, and every row is exact. Prove that the left and right columns are also complexes. Also prove that if any two of the columns are exact, so is the third.

I'm self working on problems on Aluffi's Algebra book. This is the very last problem on Chapter III. Any help in solving this much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have a whole lot of different statements to prove here.  Have you tried proving some of them to start?

Comment: Example: let $d'$ be the putative differential of $L$, and call $i$ the map of complexes $L\to M$, let $d$ be the differential of $M$. You want to check that $d'd'=0$. Because $i$ is injective, it suffices you check that $id'd'=0$. But $id'd'=did'=ddi'=0$. Try a similar argument for the putative differential of $N$.

Comment: A similar diagram chase should give you the last statement, which you can prove using the LES of a SEC of complexes if you want to be succinct.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I struggled. That's why I put it here. @PedroTamaroff, what is a putative differential ?

Comment: I mean, you don't know that $d'$ is a differential, you want to prove it is one. Saying that $L$ and $N$ are complexes means that the successive composition of the vertical maps are zero, which I write as $d'd'=0$ and $d''d''=0$, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets label the arrows to make life easier. We have:
\begin{align}
&\partial^L_n\colon L_{n}\longrightarrow L_{n-1},\\
&\partial^M_n\colon M_{n}\longrightarrow M_{n-1},\\
&\partial^N_n\colon N_{n}\longrightarrow N_{n-1},\\
&\alpha_n \colon L_n \to M_n\\
&\beta_n \colon M_n \to N_n
\end{align}

Now we want to show that $\partial^L_{i} \circ \partial^L_{i+1} = \partial^N_{i} \circ \partial^N_{i+1} = 0$. By commutativity of your diagram we have:
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{i-1}\circ\partial^L_{i} \circ \partial^L_{i+1} = \underbrace{\partial^M_{i}\circ\partial^M_{i+1}}_{\text{$=\ 0$}}\circ\alpha_{i+1} = 0
\end{equation}
where $\partial^M_{i}\circ\partial^M_{i+1} = 0$ since the middle column is a complex. Hence $\partial^L_{i} \circ \partial^L_{i+1} = 0$, since $\alpha$ is injective.

This shows that the left-hand column is a complex. Can you do the same for the right?

Comment: I tried but still couldn't get it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I still couldn't prove the rest of the problem. I would be much appreciate any suggestions.